# A* sort open list std::set by smallest F value

Tags: c++, sorting

What is the fastest and most efficient way to check the open set for the smallest value in a star? I tried to iterate through the set checking if the f value was smaller than the current one but that didn't work. I seen that sorting the open set by the F values and then just popping the front off the list was a good way to do this. However I'm not sure how to do this with my node structure.

```
struct node {
    node *parent;
    int x, y;
    int f, g, h;
    int walkable;
}
```

Code I was using to find the smallest F value(not working):

```
for (std::set<node>::iterator it = openSet.begin(); it != openSet.end(); it++) {
    if ((*it).f < grid[currentNode.y][currentNode.x].f)
        currentNode = *it;
}
```

Comment: You could write `for(const auto& n : openSet){ if(n.f < grid[cn.y][cn.x].f) cn = n;}` instead, if you're using C++11 or later.

Comment: Try search for "std::set struct custom comparator"?